# Facebook oAuth missing Continue button when in-app browser

Tags: ios, facebook, oauth, facebook-login

I have a website which also is accessible from an iOS app using an in-app browser.

When trying to sign up using the iOS browser it takes me to Facebook's login page where I first log into Facebook, then I see the app's icons and statement what Facebook will be accessing and that this doesn't allow the app to post on my Facebook. But the continue-button is missing.

When accessing the same page using a desktop or mobile browser (have tested both Chrome and Safari on mobile), the continue-button is there as it should be.

Screenshot of in-app browser with missing button.
[image: There should be a Continue button below the "Edit This"-text]

What should I do? :)
Thanks in advance

Edit: Spelling